# How to handle string data in ML classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

Hello I am a beginner in Machine Learning, I have previously worked with some binary ml tasks where the data was numerical. Now I am facing an issue where I have to find the probability of a particular combination. I can not disclose the dataset or the code at this point. My data is a dataframe of 10 columns. I have to train my model on 8 columns and predict the possibility of the last 2 columns. That is my labels are a combination of the last 2 columns. What I am facing a problem with is, these column values are not numerical. I have tried everything I came across but can't find any suitable means of converting this to numerical values. I have tried LabelEncoder from sklearn,which works with the labels, but throws memory error if I use it again. I have tried to_numeric from pandas, which reads all the values as Nan. The values are in the form '2be74fad-4d4'. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated about how to handle this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To convert categorical data to numerical, you can try these approaches in sklearn:

1. [Label Encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)
2. [Label Binarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html)
3. [OneHot Encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)

Now, for your problem, you can use LabelEncoder. But there is a catch. In other sklearn models, you can declare it once and then use it to fit and then transform on a number of columns.

In LabelEncoding, you have to `fit_transform` the model on one column in train data and then `transform` the same column in test data. Then the same process for the next categorial column.

You can iterate over a list of categorical columns to make it simple. Consider the snippet below:

```
cat_cols = ['Item_Identifier', 'Item_Fat_Content', 'Item_Type', 'Outlet_Identifier', 
         'Outlet_Size', 'Outlet_Location_Type', 'Outlet_Type', 'Item_Type_Combined']
enc = LabelEncoder()

for col in cat_cols:
    train[col] = train[col].astype('str')
    test[col] = test[col].astype('str')
    train[col] = enc.fit_transform(train[col])
    test[col] = enc.transform(test[col])
```

Comment: do we have specific ML models that are able to treat categorical string values by themselves? (i.e. there is no need for labelEncoding, OneHot encoding etc.)

Comment: @Hossein You can try CatBoost. Works great for categorical data with minimum preprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary with the mapping form a string to integer. An example can be found here: [enter link description here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-one-hot-encode-sequence-data-in-python/). Then you use onehot encoding or just feed the integer to the neural network. If the characters have some meaning you could also do it on a per character base instead of wordbased. But that depends on the task. If this String is a unique identifier of the column or so, just leave it away and don't feed it to your model.